# LINQ - Get records from one table, with second table multi record matching

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I am working on a system where I am given a SQL database where there are no relationships (please dont get me started on this).

A table that I have is bank accounts, id, sort code, account number, name.
A second table that I have is a payments table, this has 6 fields, for account number and sort code, but I only need to match on one pair (sort code and account number)

So, I have a query that gets all the bank accounts like this

```
var bankAccounts =
            _databaseContext.BankAccounts
                .Where(accounts => model.BankAccountIds
                    .Any(x => x == accounts.Id))
                .ToList();
```

I am building a query and

```
_databaseContext.Payments.Where(x => bankAccounts.Any(b => b.AccountNumber == x.AccountNumber) 
                                  && bankAccounts.Any(b => b.SortCode == x.SortCode));
```

However, when I run this I get the error

> ystem.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet()
> .Where(p => bankAccounts_0
> .Any(b => b.AccountNumber == p.AccountNumber) && bankAccounts_0
> .Any(b => b.SortCode == p.SortCode))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

So, what I need is to be able to write the query in such a way it gets me all the payments that are made where the sort code and account number match in the payments table to the bank accounts table

And I do realise that if we had the relationship between the tables this would be much simpler, however as contractor, I have little clout as to how they architect things

-- Edit

In Datacontext in `OnModelCreating` I was also doing this, but when seeding the data this dies - just building now to get the exception it throws

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<BankAccount>()
            .HasMany(payment => payment.Payments)
            .WithOne(bankAccount => bankAccount.BankAccountDetails)
            .HasPrincipalKey(x => new {x.AccountNumber, x.SortCode});
```

Then when running the code I get this

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to track an entity of type 'BankAccount' because alternate key property 'AccountNumber' is null. If the alternate key is not used in a relationship, then consider using a unique index instead. Unique indexes may contain nulls, while alternate keys may not.

Comment: Even though there are no relationships (assume by this you mean there are no FKs in the entire db) in the DB, you could still configure the navigations on the client side so EF knows how to make joins.. Also wanted to point out that the query you write with two Any is not a join on a pair of values. "payments where there is any bank account account that matches the payment account and there is any bank account sortcode that matches the payment sort code" is probably just "true" in the context

Comment: Have you tried ```Contains```, instead of ```Any```?

Comment: @JohnDoe, yea, I get compile errors at that point

Comment: @CaiusJard I tried that too, and it did cause me some problems because not all the fields have values in the payments table

Comment: Tried what too?

Comment: using the navigation properties

Comment: So you do have navigation properties correctly configured?

Comment: @CaiusJard I have since removed them, because of them because of the issues they were giving an is The PK on the bank account table is a Guid, but I need to do matching on sort code and account number.  I am just editing the question with what I had.  This typicaly dies when adding seed data as it needs to be deployable to any customer

Comment: @CaiusJard, when i have the above in the navigation properties I get this `System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to track an entity of type 'BankAccount' because alternate key property 'AccountNumber' is null. If the alternate key is not used in a relationship, then consider using a unique index instead. Unique indexes may contain nulls, while alternate keys may not.`

Comment: @SimonPrice what you try to do is equivalent to `ID in (1,2,3,6,..)`,. To get that you need to use `Contains`, not `Any`. There's no way to convert that `List.Any(x.id)` to SQL - there are no lists or arrays in T-SQL. If you tried `Contains` and got errors, post the code you used. Did you try `.Where(accounts => accountIds.Contains(account.Id))`? The list of IDs has to be a list of just IDs, not complex objects with `Id` properties.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I dont have the id in the payments table, which is why i have to go by account number and sort code

Comment: You have to use linq to sql Query not EF for this purpose as EF core always looks for physical related entities to load the data on lazy loaded bases or eager loaded bases. Use linq to sql to join both the entities by using joins

Comment: Fluent api wouldn't work until you have any physical relations

Comment: @SimonPrice EF Core is an ORM, not a replacement for SQL. Instead of trying to JOIN tables, create proper relations and let EF Core create the JOINs.

Comment: @KamranKhan pretty sure "physical relations" means something different in your mind to what it does in mine :D but if you mean the database has to have foreign keys for EF to work, that simply isn't true..

Comment: @SimonPrice what is the point of having records in BankAccount where the fundamental piece of data (the account number) is null? I think the first step you need to take is cleaning up your data. All you'll end up doing with this round-the-houses patching and bodging a client side "solution" to bad data, is low performance, and obscure bugs

Answer (score 1):

what you try to do is equivalent to `ID in (1,2,3,6,..)`,. To get that the code must use`Contains`, not `Any`.

There's no way to convert that `List.Any(x.id)` to SQL.

- First, there are no lists or arrays in T-SQL, so EF Core couldn't send that array to the server.
- Second, `bankAccounts` contains complex objects, not values. EF Core would have to generate a table type with all relevant fields and send it to the server for use in a subquery.

In T-SQL we'd write:

```
Select * 
From Payments
Where AccountNumber in (....) AND SortCode in (...)
```

To do the same in LINQ we need `Contains`. To use it the list of values should contain individual simple values:

```
var accNumbers=bankAccounts.Select(b => b.AccountNumber).ToList();
var sortCodes=bankAccounts.Select(b => b.SortCode).ToList();

var payments = _databaseContext.Payments.Where(x =>
        accNumbers.Contains(x.AccountNumber) 
        && sortCodes.Contains(x.SortCode));
```

Comment: I have had something similar to that, but will try this now

Comment: that returns 0 results, where I should have hundreds of records back

Comment: Are you sure the condition is correct? The query you posted in the question looks for payments that have both a account number *and* a sort code in these lists. If you want either one to match you need to use `||`. If either one can be NULL you need to explicitly check for that. `NULL IN (...)` will always fail

Comment: I need to match on both, not just the one

Comment: *To get that the code must useContains, not Any.* - I disagree: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgEVb.png

Comment: Also, `Where AccountNumber in (....) AND SortCode in (...)` isn't the logic that the OP is looking for because it is not coordinated; if you have BankAccounts of (12,999) and (34,888) and a payments with account details of (12,888) and (34,999) they would return from that query even though the bank accs don't actually exist. This needs either a `acc JOIN pay ON acc.acc = pay.acc and acc.sort = pay.sort` or it needs proper subquery correlation e.g. `from acc where exists(from pay where pay.sort=acc.sort and pay.acc = acc.acc)`. It cannot be done with two uncoordinated INs

Comment: (Though I agree that the OP's second attempt, that digs simple properties out of complex would not translate i.e. `bankAccounts.Any(b => b.AccountNumber == x.AccountNumber)` but it's not correct to say that it is the Any is at fault - it's just that this particular application of it won't work)

Answer (score 0):

New version, after clarificaiton in comments:
I think you could do it as one query instead of materialize the bankAccounts -list first, maybe try some like this:

```
_databaseContext.Payments
    .Where(p=>_databaseContext.BankAccounts.Where(accounts => model.BankAccountIds.Contains(accounts.Id) && accounts.AccountNumber==p.AccountNumber  && accounts.SortCode==p.SortCode ))
```

---

I think the problem is that LINQ cannot translate the list of bankAccounts to SQL, try to make a list of the AccountNumbers and SortCode as `List<string>` and do something like this:

```
var bankAccounts =
            _databaseContext.BankAccounts
                .Where(accounts => model.BankAccountIds.Contains(accounts.Id))
                .ToList();

var accountNumbers=bankAccounts.Select(x=>x.AccountNumber).ToList();
var sortCodes=bankAccounts.Select(x=>x.SortCode).ToList();

_databaseContext.Payments.Where(x => accountNumbers.Contains(x.AccountNumber) && sortCodes.Contains(x.SortCode));
```

Comment: No, I thougt you already had fetched the bankaccounts, since you have a ToList().

Comment: You do appreciate that this doesn't establish any correlation between an account number and a sort code?

Comment: @CaiusJard - Yes, same as in the Question

Comment: But, that's not what is being asked for..

Comment: hopefully for clarification, payment table has account number and sort code, and bank account will have the same.  I need to have a match on both conditions for it to bring back the required data.

Comment: this gives back 0 results where I should have hundreds

Comment: @SimonPrice try new version as one query to match both accountnumer and sortcode. The 0 rows can have with the Any-Contains thing - updated the old answer aswell

Comment: @SimonPrice this means that either the data isn't what you assumed or the condition is wrong. Post a sample of the data

Comment: Where does model come from in your edit?

Comment: @SimonPrice model is from question, I guess it's some kind of viewmodel with a list of selected accounts

Answer (score 0):

Realistically, you're looking for an SQL like:

```
SELECT *
FROM Payments p
WHERE 
  EXISTS(
    SELECT null 
    FROM BankAccounts ba
    WHERE  
      ba.BankAccountId IN (some,list,of,guids,from,your,model) AND 
      ba.AccountNumber = p.AccountNumber AND
      ba.SortCode = p.SortCode
  )
```

Your having downloaded the bank acounts (`ToList()`ed them) first actually actively cripples EF's ability to do this; it can't see a way to create the coordinated subquery any more, as it's no longer a database-based collection but a collection from the client side. As far as I know, EF supports no notion of building a value set from complex client-provided data and joining to it.

If you keep your "these certain bank accounts" operation as a database-based enumerable your EF might be able to translate it to something like the above :

```
_databaseContext.Payments.Where(pay => 
    _databaseContext.BankAccounts.Where(
      ba => model.BankAccountIds.Any(mba => mba == ba.Id)
    ).Any(ba => 
        ba.AccountNumber == pay.AccountNumber &&
        ba.SortCode == pay.SortCode
    )
);
```

The `.Any(mba => mba == ba.Id)` will translate to IN so long as it's truly a simple prop; you could also use `model.BankAccountIds.Contains(ba.Id)` but in either case the model literally needs a list of bank account guids for this restriction to translate. The `.Any(ba =>`  can translate to a coordinated `EXISTS`.

Even if it does work, I'd say you have some data modelling issues to work out - having to write a full client app like this is a headache..

---

You noted that "it doesn't work", but in my tests (which are as close as I can get them to the scenario you posted) there wasn't any problem at all:

[image]

On the left you can see my tables: BankAccounts and Payments. They both have AccountNumber and SortCode which are never the PK, they have no FKs, the payments Ac/Sort may be null. In the middle is the query I recommended you, with the only fudge above it being me making something like what I assume your model is: a root object that holds a property called BankAccountIds that is a collection of guids. On the right, you can see the generated query; it's come out fairly identically to the SQL posted initially. I use EF Core 5

Examine what is different between what I've set up, and what you have. Post your models. Post the exact query that doesn't work

Comment: sorry for not coming back to you yesterday, had to dash off... I will try this first thing in the morning thanks

Comment: Never a problem!

Comment: still throws me the same errors im getting.  I have a way to do it, by going through each of the bank accounts and then matching a one to one, but its not my preferred way.  I'll work on the company and get them to look at seeing if we can add more into the data structure.

Comment: Must be something else going on then, because I've just set up, as near as I can tell, something identical to your setup and it works fine. See the edit